# Windows password changes every 90 days, Credential password is out of sync and job fails

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a scheduled SQL Server job that runs an SSIS package.  The package obtains a flat file from a shared network drive and transfers the data to a SQL db on the SQL Server.  The job is owned by sa and the package uses my Windows Credentials to get access to the shared drive.  Without my credentials, it cannot access the shared network drive.

Unfortunately, my company requires that I update my Windows password every 90 days.  If I do not update that password in the Credentials window, the scheduled job fails (as you might imagine).

What are my options in terms of not having to update the password in Credentials every 90 days?  I feel like this something that comes up a lot, but Google searches have proved fruitless.  Hopefully I'm both thorough in my explanation and asking the question correctly.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Cheers,

Josh

Comment: If it is an automated process, you probably shouldn't be using your own domain account.

Comment: @Ellesedil Thanks - I am using my own domain account because it is the only one I've been able to use that has access to that shared network drive/folder.

Comment: Why are you using your credentials to run the package? I think pretty much all SQL shops use a system account to run their jobs and packages to avoid these kind of issues. If only your account has access to shared drives and job then ask your system admin to assign the same privileges to the SA account as yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to request that a unexpiring service account be created or an existing one is granted appropriate access to the network share. If they provide any pushback, escalate to your boss. "What if I win the lottery or you get tired of seeing my face and can me? This process is going to fail. That is an unacceptable risk"

Otherwise, you're looking at updating the credential every 90 days.

```
ALTER CREDENTIAL [ABC] WITH IDENTITY = N'home\billinkc', SECRET = N'NewP@ssword1'
```

I don't know of any way to hook the password change to also push your credentials there and hope it wouldn't be possible as it is.

Comment: And NEVER use sa to run jobs, that's just a poor practice altogether.

Comment: @billinkc I had a talk with my friend who works in IT and he said this is the best route to go.  Appreciate the help everyone has offered.